# overload operator[] on return type

Tags: c++

There is something that is troubling my brain since a moment: I am trying to overload the [] operator based on the return type. Here is what I need to do:

```
class A {

private:
    double* data_;
    int N_;
public:
    A (N=0):N_(N){
        data_ = new double[N];
    }
    ~A {delete[] data_;}

    double operator[] (const int i) {
        return data_[i];
    }

    double* operator[] (const int i) {
        return &data[i]; // for example; in fact here i need to return some block of data_ 
    }
};
```

This code won't compile; and that is my problem. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

PS: I know how to overload normal functions on the return type for example:

```
int foo ();
string foo ();
```

I used some tricks that I read in this forum. In this way:

```
struct func {
    operator string() { return "1";}
    operator int() { return 2; }
};

int main( ) {
    int x    = func(); // calls int version
    string y = func(); // calls string version
    double d = func(); // calls int version
    cout << func() << endl; // calls int version
    func(); // calls neither
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: "*PS: i know how to overload normal functions on the return type for example*" Are you sure about that?

Comment: What forum are you talking about?

Comment: Can you please tell us how to overload purely on return type? I think many people here would like to know too, since they dont know...

Comment: just follow this link [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type

Comment: @user1427050 : That link says it can't be done in C++. What are you getting at?

Comment: That actually isn't *a (normal) function* being overloaded, nor is it 
*overloading* a function. It is a trick to introduce some syntactic sugar now, and a lot of confusion later. Wrong language, I know, but have a look at [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). I think "Explicit is better than implicit." is a good one here.

Answer (score 14):

Two method overloads must have different *signatures*. The return type is not part of the signature of a method.

Comment: +1; C++11 citation, §1.3.20: "***signature** <class member function>: name, parameter type list, class of which the function is a member, cv-qualifiers (if any), and ref-qualifier (if any)*"

Answer (score 4):

You can use the same "trick" that you use for functions, that is use a proxy object with conversion operators:

```
class A
{
  private:
    double* data_;
    int N_;
  public:
    A (int N = 0)
      : N_(N), data_(new double[N])
    {}
    ~A() { delete[] data_; }

    struct proxy
    {
        int i;
        double * data;
        operator double() const
        {
            return data[i];
        }

        operator double*()
        {
            return &data[i];
        }

        operator double const *() const
        {
            return &data[i];
        }
    };

    proxy operator[] (int const i) {
        proxy p { i, data_ };        
        return p;
    }

    proxy const operator[] (int const i) const {
        proxy p { i, data_ };        
        return p;
    }
};

int main()
{
  {
    A a(12);

    double d = a[0];
    double * pd = a[0];
  }

  {
    A const ca(12);

    double d = ca[0];
    //double * pd = ca[0]; // does not compile thanks to overloads on const
    double const * pcd = ca[0];
  }
}
```

However, I would argue that this is a *terrible* idea. Having your `operator[]` return either a value or a pointer to this value is guaranteed to confuse the users of your class, in addition to making it impractical to use in expressions where both types are possible. For instance, `std::cout << a[0];` would not compile (ambiguous overloads).

Comment: Nice effort, but +1 for mentioning it is a *terrible* idea.

Comment: thanks! finally i decided to create another member function instead to overload the 'operator[]'

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like that:

```
class A {

private:
    double* data_;
    int N_;
    ... // other stuff
public:
    double operator[] (const int i) const { // note const here
        return data_[i];
    }

    double& operator[] (const int i) { // note reference here
        return data_[i];
    }
};
```

also operator should be public to have a sense.

Comment: in fact what i need is to return a set {data_[i], data_[i+1]} of 2 double (this is possible by using some SSE instrinsics)...

Comment: Note that after you have operator define like I wrote you can use it like that: '&object[i]' and you will get address/pointer you need for some other processing.