# How do I call template array operator overloading function?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I need to create an adapter C++ class, which accepts an integer index, and retrieves some types of data from a C module by the index, and then returns it to the C++ module.

The data retrieving functions in the C module are like:

```
int getInt(int index);
double getDouble(int index);
const char* getString(int index);
// ...and etc.
```

I want to implement an array-like interface for the C++ module, so I created the following class:

```
class Arguments {
public:
    template<typename T> T operator[] (int index);
};

template<> int Arguments::operator[] (int index) { return getInt(index); }
template<> double Arguments::operator[] (int index) { return getdouble(index); }
template<> std::string Arguments::operator[] (int index) { return getString(index); }
```

*(Template class doesn't help in this case, but only template member functions)*

The adapter class is no biggie, but calling the `Arguments::operator[]` is a problem!

I found out that I can only call it in this way:

```
Arguments a;
int i = a.operator[]<int>(0);       // OK
double d = a.operator[]<double>(1); // OK

int x = a[0];                       // doesn't compile! it doesn't deduce.
```

**But it looks like a joke, doesn't it?**

If this is the case, I would rather create normal member functions, like `template<T> T get(int index)`.

So here comes the question: if I create array-operator-overloading function `T operator[]()` and its specializations, is it possible to call it like accessing an array?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [overload operator\[\] on return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824569/overload-operator-on-return-type)

Comment: If there is no way to deduce the `T`, then you must provide what `T` is.  Assign the return value to something does not deduce what `T` is, so you must provide it.

Comment: overloading operators sometimes isnt as fun as one would like. If you don't like the syntax of the operator use a named method

Comment: meh, just after writing the answer I realized that the proposed dupe has a very similar answer. This is a duplicate, but I don't want to hammer it :/ please someone else do it

Comment: @Botje yes, thank you very much. that post does answer my question. it provided the same solution as idclev provided in this thread. so many smart people :)

Comment: @idclev463035818 I would rather keep your answer here :) your solution works in the same way, but I think your sample code is more intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: No, not possible. You cannot overload a function based on its return type. See here for a similar quesiton: [overload operator[] on return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824569/overload-operator-on-return-type)

However, there is a trick that lets you deduce a type from the lhs of an assignment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct container;
struct helper {
    container& c;
    size_t index;
    template <typename T> operator T();
};

struct container {
    helper operator[](size_t i){
        return {*this,i};
    }
    template <typename T> 
    T get_value(size_t i){
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,int>) {
            return 42;
        } else {
            return 0.42;
        }
    }
};

template <typename T> 
helper::operator T(){
    return c.get_value<T>(index);
}

int main() {
    container c;
    int x = c[0];
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    double y = c[1];
    std::cout << y ;
}
```

Output is:

```
42
0.42
```

The line `int x = c[0];` goes via `container::get_value<int>` where the `int` is deduced from the type of `x`. Similarly `double y = c[1];` uses `container::get_value<double>` because `y` is `double`.

The price you pay is lots of boilerplate and using `auto` like this

```
auto x = c[1];
```

will get you a `helper`, not the desired value which might be a bit unexpected.

Comment: ahahaha!! beautiful! I gave it a try and it worked. to be honest, when I posted the question, "no way" is the expected answer. as I understand your solution, the type deduction doesn't work for return type but works for conversion operator. so you let the `operator[]` always returns a delegate object which exposes an `operator T()`. in this way, you make the type deduction possible. smart! thanks.

Comment: @Zhou I have to admit, it is something I never used in production. Its interesting that something like this is possible, but for what I do daily this is a bit too "clever"

Comment: hm... yo're right. when I was working in an IBM middleware team many years ago, we just used "C with classes". No clever tricks at all. But now I am creating my own stuff in Github, so..."we're here for a reason, to have fun" :)