# Does Haskell have return type overloading?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

Based on what I've read about Haskell, and the experimentation I've done with GHC, it seems like Haskell has return type overloading (aka ad hoc polymorphism). One example of this is the `fromInteger` function which can give you a `Double` or an `Integer` depending on where the result is used. For example:

```
fd :: Double -> String
fd x = "Double"

fi :: Integer -> String
fi x = "Integer"

fd (fromInteger 5)  -- returns "Double"
fi (fromInteger 5)  -- returns "Integer"
```

[A Gentle Introduction to Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html) seems to agree with this when it says:

> The kind of polymorphism that we have talked about so far is commonly called parametric polymorphism. There is another kind called ad hoc polymorphism, better known as overloading. Here are some examples of ad hoc polymorphism:
>
> - The literals 1, 2, etc. are often used to represent both fixed and arbitrary precision integers.

If the numeric literals are considered to be an example of ad hoc polymorphism (aka overloading), then it seems that the same is true for the result of functions like `fromInteger`.

And in fact, I've found some answers to [other questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type) that suggest that Haskell has overloading by return type.

However, at least one Haskell programmer has told me that this isn't return type overloading, and is instead an example of "parametric polymorphism, where the parameter is bound by a universal quantifier".

I *think* what he's getting at is that `fromInteger` is returning a value from every instance of `Num` (sort of a nondeterministic type).

That seems like a reasonable interpretation, but as far as I can tell, Haskell never lets us look at more than one of these instance values (thanks in part to the [Monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction)). It also seems like the actual instance who's value we look at can be determined statically. Because of all of this, it seems reasonable to say that in the expression `fd (fromInteger 5)` the subexpression `fromInteger 5` is of type `Double`, while in the expression `fi (fromInteger 5)` the subexpression `fromInteger 5` is of type `Integer`.

So, does Haskell have return type overloading?

If not, please provide an example of one of the following:

- valid Haskell code that would have different behavior if Haskell had return type overloading
- valid Haskell code that would be invalid if Haskell had return type overloading
- invalid Haskell code that would be valid if Haskell had return type overloading

Comment: Can you say carefully what you consider the difference between parametric polymorphism and return-type overloading to be?

Comment: @DanielWagner I appreciate your desire for more clarity, but if it were only about what *I* consider to be the difference then I wouldn't need to ask this question. I'd just do an experiment based on my personal definition. These aren't terms I made up, however.  "Return-type overloading" is a form of ad hoc polymorphism, rather than a form of parametric polymorphism.

Comment: That said, here's one thing that suggests that this is not (just) parametric polymorphism: From Wikipedia, parametric polymorphism makes it possible to "handle values identically **without depending on their type**", so if `Num a => a` is parametric polymorphism then I'd expect `Num a =>` would mean "the type of `a` is some instance of `Num`, you can't rely on which". It would *only* let you perform operations that applied to *all* instances of `Num`, but Haskell lets you perform operations on a `Num a => a` that only apply to *specific* instance of `Num`.  You **can depend on their type**.

Comment: Another thing: ML has parametric polymorphism, but very limited ad hoc polymorphism.  It's been years since I did anything with ML so please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that it is not possible in ML to have a function like `fromInteger` where the result can be given to both a function that accepts only `Integer` and also to one that accepts only `Double` (modulo whatever the types in ML are called). This suggests that either Haskell has a more powerful form of parametric polymorphism, or that the difference is not coming from parametric polymorphism.

Comment: Aha! I'm very glad you clarified. In that case, the answer is an unqualified, "Yes, Haskell has ad-hoc polymorphism, including in its return types."! As detailed below, that actually doesn't give you anything you couldn't get with parametric polymorphism and a little pain (in fact, the very first thing GHC does is compile the ad-hoc polymorphism into parametric polymorphism), but _gosh dang_ is it convenient. (By the way, this is not the only implementation strategy; for example, at least one implementation actually keeps type information at runtime to do class dispatch.)

Comment: @DanielWagner I think "that actually doesn't give you anything you couldn't get with parametric polymorphism and a little pain" might be part of the reason some Haskell programmers seem to be reluctant to say that this is ad hoc polymorphism, but you can achieve everything any high level language can do with assembly and a little pain.

Comment: @DanielWagner Further clarification: I guess part of what I'm asking is, is it reasonable to say that in the expression `fd (fromInteger 5)` the subexpression `fromInteger 5` is of type `Double`, while in the expression `fi (fromInteger 5)` the subexpression `fromInteger 5` is of type `Integer`?

Comment: Yes, I think that's reasonable. Of course, I'm also of the bent to treat "`A` is of type `B`" as a _relation_ (not a function) between `A` and `B` until proven otherwise. In particular, in Haskell, it is definitively not a function: some well-typed expressions can be given many distinct types.

Answer (score 17):

Well, one way to look at it is that Haskell translates the return type polymorphism that you're thinking of into parametric polymorphism, using something called the **dictionary-passing translation** for type classes.  (Though this is not the only way to implement type classes or reason about them; it's just the most popular.)

Basically, `fromInteger` has this type in Haskell:

```
fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a
```

That might be translated internally into something like this:

```
fromInteger# :: NumDictionary# a -> Integer -> a
fromInteger# NumDictionary# { fromInteger = method } x = method x

data NumDictionary# a = NumDictionary# { ...
                                       , fromInteger :: Integer -> a
                                       , ... }
```

So for each concrete type `T` with a `Num` instance, there's a `NumDictionary# T` value that contains a function `fromInteger :: Integer -> T`, and all code that uses the `Num` type class is translated into code that takes a dictionary as the argument.

Comment: So, is that a "yes" or a "no"?

Comment: I find it too hilarious that your explanation starts with "basically".

Comment: Yes, I understand this interpretation, but my question is whether this interpretation yields behavior that is in any way different from what is commonly called "return type overloading" in other languages. The one place where I could imagine them being different would be if I could somehow invoke `fromInteger#` on the same `x` multiple times but with different `NumDictionary#` dictionaries. I'm pretty sure the monomorphism restriction plugs all of the places that would be possible, however, yielding something which is behaviorally identical to return type overloading.

Comment: If you want a clear-cut "yes" or "no" answer, maybe you could articulate your criteria?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves I don't really think the monomorphism restriction makes a difference here. That restriction is there to raise awareness of the fact that an overloaded "constant" is not really a constant and using it may trigger further computation.

Comment: Well, the point of the dictionary translation is to *eliminate* overloading from the language at a lower-level layer, and this is done by reducing ad-hoc polymorphism to parametric polymorphism. I think it's fair to say that Haskell, as a squishy, general rule, regards parametric polymorphism as more fundamental than ad-hoc. GHC Core for example is based on a polymorphic lambda calculus (System F) with extensions.  Whether the translation gives you "true" ad-hoc polymorphism strikes me as less interesting than the fact that one type of polymorphism is eliminated for the other.

Comment: @sacundim It strikes me as a bit weird to think about what's done at a lower level layer of a particular implementation to be somehow "more fundamental". By that reasoning couldn't one say that at an even lower level, every Haskell implementation uses side effects, so at a fundamental level Haskell is not purely functional?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves: that's a fair question. I don't think I'm not going to be able to do this justice in 600 characters, but the [polymorphic lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) is really, really fundamental to Haskell not because it's "low level" but because it's central (informally put); it's the framework that the language's authors use as a model to reason about its semantics. If you read the papers on various features of Haskell and GHC (type classes, existential, rank-n types, etc.) the polymorphic lambda calculus or a modification of it is usually there.

Answer (score 14):

The seminal paper on Haskell-style typeclasses is called ["How to make ad-hoc polymorphism less ad hoc"](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/type-classes.html).  So, the answer to your question is a qualified "yes" -- depending on just how ad hoc you require your return-type overloading to be...

In other words:  there is no question that ad hoc polymorphism is *relevant* to typeclasses, since that was a motivating example for inventing them.  But whether you think the result still qualifies as "return-type overloading" depends on the fiddly details of your favored definition.

Comment: I absolutely concur with this answer.

Comment: I'm still having trouble seeing why this is a *qualified* yes. Can you think of a "fiddly detail" that would *disqualify* the type of ad hoc polymorphism in Haskell typeclasses from having "return-type overloading"?

Answer (score 12):

I'd like to address one small part of your question:

> It also seems like the actual instance who's value we look at can be determined statically.

This isn't really accurate. Consider the following wacky data type:

```
data PerfectlyBalancedTree a
    = Leaf a
    | Branch (PerfectlyBalancedTree (a,a))
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
```

Let's gawk at that type for a second first before we move on to the good bits. Here are a few typical values of the type `PerfectlyBalancedTree Integer`:

```
Leaf 0
Branch (Leaf (0, 0))
Branch (Branch (Leaf ((0,0),(0,0))))
Branch (Branch (Branch (Leaf (((0,0),(0,0)),((0,0),(0,0))))))
```

In fact, you can visualize any value of this type as being an initial sequence of n `Branch` tags followed by a "we're finally done, thank goodness" `Leaf` tag followed by a 2^n-tuple of the contained type. Cool.

Now, we're going to write a function to parse a slightly more convenient representation for these. Here's a couple example invocations:

```
*Main> :t fromString
fromString :: String -> PerfectlyBalancedTree Integer
*Main> fromString "0"
Leaf 0
*Main> fromString "b(42,69)"
Branch (Leaf (42,69))
*Main> fromString "bbb(((0,0),(0,0)),((0,0),(0,0)))"
Branch (Branch (Branch (Leaf (((0,0),(0,0)),((0,0),(0,0))))))
```

Along the way, it will be convenient to write a slightly more polymorphic function. Here it is:

```
fromString' :: Read a => String -> PerfectlyBalancedTree a
fromString' ('b':rest) = Branch (fromString' rest)
fromString' leaf = Leaf (read leaf)
```

Now our real function is just the same thing with a different type signature:

```
fromString :: String -> PerfectlyBalancedTree Integer
fromString = fromString'
```

But wait a second... what just happened here? I slipped something by you big time! Why didn't we just write this directly?

```
fromStringNoGood :: String -> PerfectlyBalancedTree Integer
fromStringNoGood ('b':rest) = Branch (fromStringNoGood rest)
fromStringNoGood leaf = Leaf (read leaf)
```

The reason is that in the recursive call, *`fromStringNoGood` has a different type*. It's not being called on to return a `PerfectlyBalancedTree Integer`, it's being called on to return a `PerfectlyBalancedTree (Integer, Integer)`. We could write ourselves such a function...

```
fromStringStillNoGood :: String -> PerfectlyBalancedTree Integer
fromStringStillNoGood ('b':rest) = Branch (helper rest)
fromStringStillNoGood leaf = Leaf (read leaf)

helper :: String -> PerfectlyBalancedTree (Integer, Integer)
helper ('b':rest) = Branch ({- ... what goes here, now? -})
helper leaf = Leaf (read leaf)
```

... but this way lies an infinite regress into writing deeperly and deeperly nested types.

The problem is that, even though we're interested in a *monomorphic* top-level function, we nevertheless *cannot* determine statically what type `read` is being called at in the polymorphic function it uses! The data we're passed determines what type of tuple `read` should return: more `b`s in the `String` means a deeper-nested tuple.

Comment: The places where you have `s`... shouldn't they be `leaf`?

Comment: This is a mind-bendingly interesting problem, but it leaves me wondering how `fromString` can even compile. What does the dictionary-passing translation look like? In particular, how does it avoid the infinite regression when generating the method dictionary to pass into `fromString'#`?

Comment: Oh, I think I (at least partly) figured it out... in the expression `Branch (fromStringNoGood rest)` it constructs a new dictionary where the `read` function reads a 2-tuple, and each element is read by the passed in dictionary's `read` function. I'd still be interested in seeing what that code looks like, if possible...

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves: Well, `Read` instance for tuples is defined as `class (Read a, Read b) => Read (a,b) where {- ... -}`. Using dictionary passing translation, it's basically a function `tupleDict :: Read a -> Read b -> Read (a,b)`. Now we rewrite `fromString'` as `Read a -> String -> PerfectlyBalancedTree a` and the recursive call as `fromString' dict ('b':rest) = Branch (fromString' (tupleDict dict dict) rest)`.

Answer (score 5):

You're right: Haskell does have overloading and it provides it through its type-class mechanism.

Consider the following signatures:

```
f :: [a] -> a
g :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

The first signature tells you that given a list of elements of any type `a`, `f` will produce a value of type `a`. This means that the implementation of `f` cannot make any assumptions about the type `a` and what operations it admits. This is an example of **parametric polymorphism**. A moment's reflection reveals that there are actually very little options for implementing `f`: the only thing you can do is select an element from the provided list. Conceptually, there is a single generic implementation of `f` that works for all types `a`.

The second signatures tells you that given a list of elements of some type `a` that belongs to the type class `Num`, `g` will produce a value of that type `a`. This means that the implementation of `g` can consume, produce, and manipulate values of type `a` using all operations that come with the type class `Num`. For example, `g` can add or multiply the elements of the list, select the minimum of the list, return a lifted constant, ... This is an example of **overloading**, which is typically taken to be a form of ad-hoc polymorphism (the other main form being coercion). Conceptually, there is a different implementation for `g` for all types `a` in `Num`.

Answer (score 2):

It has return type overloading.  For a good example see the Read function.  It has the type Read a => String -> a. It can read and return anything that implements the read type class.