# Extending `read`-like behavior

Tags: haskell

I am in the process of learning Haskell, and I've come across a problem I can't seem to solve. Basically, my use case is as follows. I'm processing a string; if it begins with a `"` character, then I want to return it as a string (with `"` stripped); otherwise, I want to return the result of `read` on it. In other words:

`parse "\"foo\"" -> "foo"`

`parse "3" -> 3`

`parse "1.5" -> 1.5`

So far I've tried the following approaches.

1. Polymorphic return types

```haskell
parse :: String -> a
parse ('"':xs) = init xs -- strip closing '"'
parse string = read string
```

This gives a compile-time error `` Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `[Char]' ``. Shouldn't `a` match any type, including complex types like `[Char]`?

2. Typeclass

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}
class Parse where parse :: String -> a
instance Read a => Parse a where parse = read
instance Parse String where parse = init . tail
```

This compiles, but gives the following runtime error:

```
Overlapping instances for Parse a0 arising from a use of `parse'
Matching instances:
  instance Read a => Parse a -- Defined at parse.hs:5:14
  instance Parse [Char] -- Defined at parse.hs:7:14
(The choice depends on the instantiation of `a0'
 To pick the first instance above, use -XIncoherentInstances
 when compiling the other instance declarations)
```

`String` isn't an instance of `Read`, so I'm not quite sure where it's seeing the overlap.

BTW, the pragmas are there because otherwise I get compile-time errors:

```
Illegal instance declaration for `Parse [Char]'
  (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
   where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
   and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
   Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for `Parse [Char]'
```

and

```
Constraint is no smaller than the instance head
  in the constraint: Read a
(Use -XUndecidableInstances to permit this)
In the instance declaration for `Parse a'
```

3. Making `String` an instance of `Read`

I'm not sure how to do this, and the documentation isn't all that clear to me. If I can figure it out, though, it sounds like it might be the right thing to do. But one question sticks in my head: if in one module I make `String` an instance of `Read`, would that change the class for the entire application even if I don't export the relevant bits? If it would, then I'm not sure I like the implications of that.

---

So that's what I've tried so far. Is my approach wrong? Is it basically right and I just need to fix a couple of details? Please let me know.

Comment: It looks like you're wanting a dependently typed function since the return type is dependent on the value of its argument.  What is it you're actually trying to do, since this usually means you're going about something the wrong way?

Comment: @bheklilr: I'm trying to do exactly what I said I was trying to do: parse a string into a value of unknown type, pretty much the way the `read` function does. Why do you think this is the wrong way? And if it is the wrong way, what would be the right way?

Comment: What do you expect the code that uses this function to look like? Is it useful to not know which thing happened after calling this function? How about using `Either`?

Comment: `read` doesn't parse a value into an unknown type.  Try typing `read "1234"` into GHCi.  It doesn't work, does it?  Now enter `read "1234" :: Int`, this works because you've told `read` what type to return.  It's not that `read` is determining the return type, _you_ have to determine what return type you want from `read` before calling it.  If you don't specify an explicit signature and it still compiles this is because GHC uses type inference to figure out what type should go there, but at the end of the day `read` is not determining its return type.

Comment: @bheklilr: "`read` doesn't parse a value into an unknown type."—Yes, sorry about the inexact phrasing. By "unknown type", I meant "type that's not fully known at compile time". Of course the runtime context determines the type, and I'm well aware of that.

Comment: @31eee384: I simply don't care whether `read` was invoked or not. I'm parsing string representations of things that will go in a collection. I can already deal with the case of parsing `1 2 3` and getting a collection of `Integral`s, but I should also be able to deal with `"one" "two" "three"` and yield a collection of strings. (This is an exercise rather than a real-world project, so there's limited context.)

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser `read` still determines its type at compile time.  That's why I said that in order for it to compile GHC will determine the type needed there, but it's always caller determined polymorphism, not callee.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser Haskell doesn't really do run-time types.  What you're asking to do doesn't make much sense in Haskell anyway.  To illustrate, how would you act on any values you might parse?  If you parsed a list of strings, how would you tell it's a list of strings and not a list of ints?  You can't make a case statement that switches on the type of a value, that's not allowed.  How would you apply functions to it?

Comment: @bheklilr: None of the operations on the collection care in any way about its members' types; they're simply manipulating the elements as opaque unmodifiable things, much like list operations do, or working with common typeclasses like `Show`. In other words, the collection sort of acts like `[a]`.

Comment: @bheklilr [I take issue with your claim that `read` determines its (return) type at compile time.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11422333/791604)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Shouldn't `a` match any type, including complex types like `[Char]`?

It can and does. The question here is about who gets to choose what `a` is. The type you wrote is `parse :: String -> a` which is short for

```
parse :: forall a. String -> a
```

which you should read as: "the caller chooses a type `a` and a `String` `s`, and `parse s` produces a value of type `a`". The important part here is that it is the caller, and not `parse`, that chooses the type to substitute for `a`. So if you write

```
parse s = ""
```

this is an error, because the caller may choose a type other than `String`! You could also imagine a type where `parse` gets to choose; this is called an existential type, and it has some strong restrictions on how the caller can use the produced value.

> `String` isn't an instance of `Read`, so I'm not quite sure where it's seeing the overlap.

You're wrong: `String` *is* an instance of `Read`. It uses these two instances:

```
instance Read Char -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
instance Read a => Read [a] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
```

(Recall that `type String = [Char]`.) For example, in ghci:

```
> read "\"foo\"" :: String
"foo"
```

Perhaps this instance is enough for your purposes!

Comment: Srsly? I missed `String` being an instance of `Read`? I looked in the docs for that and didn't find it! That would explain the "overlapping types" error. Checking docs again now...

Comment: Minor point of order: `read` for `String` also modifies the `readListPrec` behavior for `[Char]` to allow reading both strings ("foo") and lists of chars (['f','o','o']). Both `Read` and `Show` allow overloading for lists to allow for things like String. The `Read` instance for strings is defined [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Read.html#line-315).

Comment: Yes, that was my problem: I didn't know that `String` was an instance of `Read`, and so I was both reimplementing `read` and creating type issues. Thanks. But...how would I know that `String` was an instance of `Read`? It doesn't seem to be in the docs.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: That may be the answer to why I couldn't find anything about `Read String` in the docs, then.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser You would have to deduce it from the facts that `Char` is an instance of `Read`, `type String = [Char]`, and `instance Read a => Read [a]`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: The last is the one I was unaware of.