# Type mysteries. Why does this code compile?

Tags: haskell

This code does not compile:

```
default ()

f :: RealFloat a => a
f = 1.0

g :: RealFloat a => a
g = 1.0

h :: Bool
h = f < g --Error. Ambiguous.
```

This is expected because it's ambiguous. The two possibilities are `Float` and `Double` and the compiler doesn't know which `<` to pick.

However, this code *does* compile:

```
default ()

f :: RealFloat a => a
f = 1.0

g :: RealFloat a => a
g = 1.0

h :: RealFloat a => a
h = f + g --Why does this compile?
```

Why? Why isn't Haskell confused here, in a similar manner as in the example above, about which `+` to pick (for `Float` or `Double`)?

Comment: An observation which may or may not help: the inferred type for `f < g` is `RealFloat a => Bool`, which is ambiguous *because* the type `a` is not mentioned on the right-hand side of the `=>`. In contrast, the inferred type for `f + g` is `RealFloat a => a`, which does not have this property -- all the type variables mentioned on the left of `=>` are also mentioned on the right.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your second example `h` *also* has a polymorphic type. So the type at which `+` is used isn't ambiguous; it just hasn't been chosen yet.

The context where `h` is *used* will determine which type's `+` is chosen (and different use-sites can make different choices). The user of `h` can ask it to provide any `RealFloat` type they please; `f` and `g` can also provide any `RealFloat` type, so `h` will just ask them for exactly the type its user is asking for.

Comment: Is it true in Haskell that the function implementations of `<` and `+` must be precisely determined at **compile-time**? (Which means we can't for `<` choose among `Float` and `Double` at runtime because that's not how Haskell works?) Kindly confirm this, because if this is the case, this whole thing is finally starting to make sense to me.

Comment: @haskellHQ Mostly yes, except that there are polymorphic values (like your f, g, h). Implementations of type class methods must be *either* statically chosen at compile time at the call site *or* passed on as a constraint (the `RealFloat =>` bit) in the type. If the constraint is passed on, the places that call *us* get to fix the implementation (or pass the constraint on again... Eventually it must be fixed).

Comment: @haskellHQ So a given `+` or `<` might actually be used with many different implementations, so you could say it's chosen at runtime; it can even be called with implementations that didn't exist when the code containing `+` or `<` was complied - it's a lot more flexible than "must be chosen at compile time" sounds like! But yes, when the choice is actually made, it's made at compile time.

Comment: @haskellHQ That is a good first approximation of the truth, but there are some wrinkles. See [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11422333/791604) for some discussion -- it centers around a `read`-like function rather than `(+)`, but the core idea is the same.

Comment: There's some substantial extra flexibility from the fact that the chosen implementation can depend on others in polymorphic recursive contexts. That's unlikely to show up in a `RealFloat` situation, but it happens in real code for other classes like `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Foldable`, `Eq`, `Ord`, `Show`, etc. Look up "nested types" and prepare to be confused for a while. Unrelatedly, `reflection` throws in extreme dynamic fun!

Answer (score 11):

With `h = f < g :: Bool`, the type `Bool` doesn't contain the polymorphic `a` variable. To actually compute the `Bool` result, the `a` needs to be instantiated, and the resulting `Bool` value can depend on the choice of `a` (through the `RealFloat` instance), so instead of making an arbitrary choice GHC refuses to compile.

With `h = f + g`, the `a` parameter is in the type of the result, therefore there is no ambiguity. The choice for `a` has not yet been made, we can still instantiate `a` as we like (or more precisely, we re-generalized the type of `f + g`).

Answer (score 5):

To precisely understand the meaning of polymorphism, I find it convenient to think about functional languages with explicit type arguments -- either theoretical ones, such as System F, or real-world ones such as Agda, Idris, Coq, etc.

In these languages, *types* are passed as function arguments as values normally are. If we have a polymorphic function

```
f :: forall a. T a
```

this actually expects a *type* as a first argument, like this:

```
f Int :: T Int
f Char :: T Char
f String :: T String
...
```

Note how the `a` in the resulting type gets instantiated to the type argument.

Adding typeclass constraints, we have that

```
f :: RealFloat a => a
f = 1.0
```

can be seen as a function expecting: 1) a type argument `a`, 2) a proof that the chosen type is a `RealFloat` (e.g. a typeclass dictionary). When this is provided, a result of the chosen type `a` will be returned. A more pedantic definition could be

```
f :: forall a. RealFloat a => a
f = \\a -> \\proof ->  ... -- use proof to generate 1.0 :: a
```

where `\\` is used as a type-level lambda, for the additional arguments described earlier. A call could then be as follows:

```
-- pseudo syntax
f Double double_is_a_RealFloat_proof
```

which will return `1.0 :: Double`.

Now, what happens if we write the posted code?

```
h :: RealFloat a => a
h = f + g
```

Well, now `f` and `g` expect type arguments, as well as `h`, since all three are polymorphic values. During type inference, a few additional arguments are added by the compiler as follows:

```
h :: forall a. RealFloat a => a
h = \\a -> \\proof -> (f a proof) + (g a proof)
```

(technically, even `+`, being polymorphic, has additional arguments, but let's put that under the rug for readability's sake...)

Note that now it is clear what type `f` should produce: it's `a`, the same type which is produced by `h`. In other words, `h` asks its caller which type is wanted, and forwards the same type to `f`. Ditto for `g`.

By comparison, in

```
h :: Bool
h = f < g
```

there's no polymorphism in `h`, but `f` and `g` are still polymorphic. During type inference the compiler reaches

```
h = (f a? proof?) < (g a? proof?)
```

and has to invent `a?` and `proof?` out of thin air, since `h` is not asking them to its caller. Hence the ambiguity error.

Finally, note that it is possible to see the additional type arguments which are added by GHC during type inference. To do that, it suffices to dump the GHC Core intermediate language, e.g. with the `-ddump-simpl` GHC flag. In GHC 8.x, which is not yet released, rumors say that we will be even allowed to specify explicit type arguments in our code when we want to, and let the compiler infer them as usual otherwise. It sounds fun!