# Type mysteries. Why does this piece of code compile?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, type-inference, ambiguity

The code

```
default ()
h :: Bool
h = 1.0 == 1.0 --Error. Ambiguity.
```

does not compile. This is expected because there is ambiguity. It could be either `Float` or `Double` and Haskell doesn't know which one we want.

But the code

```
default ()
foo :: (Fractional a, Eq a) => a -> Bool
foo x = x == 1.0
```

compiles successfully. I don't fully understand why. Why isn't this also ambiguous?

I have the feeling that this is because whenever we call `foo`, we are guaranteed to have picked a concrete type in place of `a`, i.e., we are guaranteed to have fixed `a` to either `Float` or `Double` (or our custom type that has instances of both `Fractional` and `Eq`) at compile-time and therefore there is no ambiguity.

But this is just a feeling and I don't know if it's 100% accurate.

Comment: @Carsten It doesn't at all matter that both are in `Eq`; it is illegal because choosing one could give a different result from other (for this program it wouldn't, of course, but the compiler doesn't and shouldn't know this).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov well sorry ...

Comment: Can you say carefully why this is not a duplicate of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34776282/791604)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The definition for ambiguity in this context is given in [Section 4.3.4 of Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html):

> We say that an expression `e` has an ambiguous type if, in its type `forall us. cx => t`, there is a type variable `u` in `us` that occurs in `cx` but not in `t`. Such types are invalid.

In `foo :: (Fractional a, Eq a) => a -> Bool`, there is no such variable (because `a` occurs in `a -> Bool`). In `1.0 == 1.0` the type is actually `(Fractional a, Eq a) => Bool`, so there is such a variable.

The *reason* this kind of ambiguity is an error is because there is no way for compiler to choose between different instantiations of the variable `a`, and the result of the program can depend on which one it chooses. In this case `1.0 == 1.0` should always be `True` for any *reasonable* instantiation, but 1) the compiler doesn't know this; 2) not all instantiations are reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

The second piece of code compiles because

```
foo :: (Fractional a, Eq a) => a -> Bool
foo x = x == 1.0

(==) :: Eq a => a -> a
```

so the compiler will know that the float number literal `1.0 :: Rational a => a` have the same type with `x`, which has an `Eq` instance i.e. the "meaning" of `==` in this function is deterministic for every call.

While in the first piece of code, the literal can be any type `(Rational a, Eq a) => a`, so the "meaning" of `==` is ambiguous, the value of h can be either True or False, depends on the type of the literal, which is not provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here'a another, conceptual way to put it:

Both cases have intrinsic ambiguity, but the first one is a dead end — there is no hope for the compiler to infer its way out of the ambiguity.

The second case is also ambiguous, but the ambiguity is open — whoever calls the ambiguous code, must resolve the ambiguity, or delegate/bubble it further up the call stack.

That's all there is to it — polymorphism is controlled ambiguity. The first case is uncontrolled ambiguity so it's not useful (i.e. polymorphism-related) ambiguity. So it gets rejected until it's annotated to unambiguity.