# Creating a typeclass that returns another instance of that typeclass in haskell

Tags: haskell, math, functional-programming

I'm trying to create a a system to derive symbolic functions, and I have a problem:

I have a typeclass for expressions, `Exp`, that defines a derivative function:

```
class Exp e where 
    derivative :: (Exp d) => e -> d
```

I want that class to have a few instances:

```
data Operator a b = a :* b | a :+ b

instance (Exp a, Exp b) => Exp (Operator a b)  where
    derivative (f :* g) = ((derivative f) :* g) :+ (f :* (derivative g)) --The derivative of the multiplication of two expressions 
    derivative (f :+ g) = derivative f :+ derivative g --The derivative of the addition of two expressions

instance Exp Double where
    derivative a = (0 :: Double)  --The derivative of a constant value is 0


instance Exp Char where
    derivative c = (1 :: Double) --The derivative of just a variable is one
```

what I get I compile with ghci is:

```
math.hs:19:21: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘d’ with actual type ‘Double’
  ‘d’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      derivative :: forall d. Exp d => Double -> d
    at math.hs:19:5
• In the expression: (0 :: Double)
  In an equation for ‘derivative’: derivative a = (0 :: Double)
  In the instance declaration for ‘Exp Double’
• Relevant bindings include
    derivative :: Double -> d (bound at math.hs:19:5)

math.hs:22:21: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘d’ with actual type ‘Double’
  ‘d’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      derivative :: forall d. Exp d => Char -> d
    at math.hs:22:5
• In the expression: (1 :: Double)
  In an equation for ‘derivative’: derivative c = (1 :: Double)
  In the instance declaration for ‘Exp Char’
• Relevant bindings include
    derivative :: Char -> d (bound at math.hs:22:5)

math.hs:28:27: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘d’
              with actual type ‘Operator (Operator a0 b) (Operator a b0)’
  ‘d’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      derivative :: forall d. Exp d => Operator a b -> d
    at math.hs:27:5
• In the expression: derivative f :+ derivative g
  In an equation for ‘derivative’:
      derivative (f :+ g) = derivative f :+ derivative g
  In the instance declaration for ‘Exp (Operator a b)’
• Relevant bindings include
    g :: b (bound at math.hs:28:22)
    f :: a (bound at math.hs:28:17)
    derivative :: Operator a b -> d (bound at math.hs:27:5)
```

My question is this: why are my instance decelerations problematic? The derivative in each always resolves into an instance of `Exp` that is required by the type constrain of `derivative`, so why can't it match the type?

Comment: The first obvious problem is that you have a type variable `d` instead of `Double` in `derivative :: (Exp d) => e -> d`.

Comment: I recommend you not use a type class here - it doesn't really have any purpose. Instead, make yourself an `Exp` data type: `data Exp = Number Double | Variable Char | Exp :* Exp | Exp :+ Exp` and then define `derivative :: Char -> Exp -> Exp` where the first argument is the variable with respect to which you are deriving.

Comment: The problem here is that you want to return _some_ type `d`, but your declaration states `derivative` returns _any_ `d`, whatever the _caller_ might choose. So, you used universal quantification instead of existential quantification. Haskell does not have existentials. One can define them e.g. with a custom GADT, but they look wrong for this -- Alec above suggests a much simpler alternative.

Comment: It looks like you're thinking in terms of object-oriented classes, with `Exp` as an abstract base class. Except for the term "class", type classes aren't very much like OO classes. A sum type, like @Alec suggests, is a much better fit.

Answer (score 5):

When you write

```
class Exp e where 
    derivative :: (Exp d) => e -> d
```

you declare that any type `e` which is in the `Exp` class should have a function `derivative :: e -> d`. Note that `e` here is a very specific class, but `d` is only said to be in `Exp`. It's almost an *arbitrary* type. So you're trying to define a function which, given an argument, returns a value of *arbitrary* type, belonging to `Exp`

Selection of `d` is left to the compiler depending on context, like [with `fromInteger`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420126/does-haskell-have-return-type-overloading). So you're not saying "for each `e` there is a `d` belonging to `Exp` such that `derivative` will return `d`", you say that "for each `e` *all* `d` belonging to `Exp` are such that `derivative` will return `d`". If you want to say the former, you will probably have to use multi-parameterized classes and functional dependencies (to specify that type of the output is uniquely determined by type of the input).

If we replace `e` with some specific type, you're trying to implement the following:

```
derivative :: Exp d => Double -> d
derivative = (0::Double)
```

Which is not something you can do, because not all `Exp`s are doubles. Say, `Operator Double Double` (which is in `Exp`) is clearly not a `Double`. Even more artificial example with the same problem:

```
derivative :: Double -> a
derivative = (0::Double)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to achieve the desired behavior, one is using `FunctionalDependencies` and `MultiParamTypeClasses`, while the other one is using `TypeFamilies`, which is showed below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Main where

class Exp e where
    type ResExp e :: * -- type family of resulting expression
    derivative :: (Exp (ResExp e)) => e -> ResExp e

instance Exp Double where
    type ResExp Double = Double
    derivative a = 0


instance Exp Char where
    type ResExp Char = Double
    derivative c = 1
```

But when it comes to the instance for `Operator`, there are two bugs in implementation:

1. Attempt to construct an infinite type
2. `derivative (f :* g)` and `derivative (f :+ g)` have different return types.

Here is a way how to solve this problem though:

```
data Mult a b = a :* b

data Plus a b = a :+ b

instance (Exp a, Exp b, Exp (ResExp a), Exp (ResExp b)) => Exp (Plus a b) where
    type ResExp (Plus a b) = (Plus (ResExp a) (ResExp b))
    derivative (f :+ g) = derivative f :+ derivative g


instance (Exp a, Exp b, Exp (ResExp a), Exp (ResExp b)) => Exp (Mult a b) where
    type ResExp (Mult a b) = Plus (Mult (ResExp a) b) (Mult a (ResExp b))
    derivative (f :* g) = ((derivative f) :* g) :+ (f :* (derivative g))
```