# Why can't I overload a function by its return type?

Tags: oop, overloading

Why can't function is not overloaded by its return types, There should no language which support such overloading. I want to know the reason that what was happening if its allow, or why its not allowing such function overloading by its return type.

```
int func();
bool func();
int main()
{
     int iret = func();
     bool bret = func();
}
```

Always arise this quetion in my mind. Hoping satisfied answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type

Answer (score 2):

A function like

```
double function fn1()
{

int a = 2;
return a;

}
```

In the above e.g. a will be implicitly converted to double when returned.

```
int function fn1()
{

double a = 2;
return a;

}
```

In the above e.g. a will be implicitly converted to int when returned.

A fn call for this fn would be like `int a = fn1();`  or `double a = fn1();`.

In either case  both definitions can cause ambiguity as to which is to be called. 
The fact that the returned values are stored in `int` or `double` doesn't make a difference in determining the fn to be called. The function is first resolved and then executed and then the return value is assigned.

If both didn't have a return type the call would be simply `fn1();` making it ambiguous, whether to call `fn1()` with return type `int` or `double`