# C# Overload return type - recommended approach

Tags: c#, .net, overloading, return-type

I have a situation where I just want the return type to be different for a method overload, but you can't do this in C#.

What's the best way to handle this? Is the fact that I need this mean my program structure flawed?

Given the fact that this is impossible in C#, what is the recommended approach?

Comment: What does the method do?

Comment: Retrieves a list of data, either as a LinkedList or a Dictionary.

Comment: With the advent of `var` keyword, this is simply impossible to implement without the ambiguity. See [function-overloading-by-return-type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Typically you simply give the methods different names.

An example of this is `IDataReader` with `GetInt32`, `GetInt64` etc.

To be honest, I believe this usually makes it clearer what you're trying to do anyway - particularly if you're then *calling* an overloaded method with the result:

```
Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32()); // This is clear

Console.WriteLine(foo.OverloadedGet()); // Which overload of OverloadedGet?
```

Comment: Accepted as answer because the fact that renaming makes it clearer is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

> Given the fact that this is impossible in C#, what is the recommended approach?

It depends on why you need this.

The most common approach is to just use a different name.  The framework does this in many cases, such as the [Convert class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert_methods.aspx).

If you want to support multiple types, you can do this via generic methods:

```
T SomeMethod<T>()
  // Optionally add constraints:"
  where T : IFoo
{
```

The generic method approach is common for repostories, as it's common that there's an "Entity" type of base class.

Answer (score 3):

You can have another parameter specifying the return type.

```
public static T[] Method1<T>(int i, T type)
{
    return new T[i];
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `T type` parameter at all for this to work.  No need for it since you're not using it ;)

Comment: @ReedCopsey It allows me to have: `string[] s1 = Method1(3, "a");` instead of `string[] s2 = Method1<string>(3);`. (No big deal. I know.)

Comment: @ReedCopsey I now see you have an answer of this type. When answering, I just saw the beginning of your answer so I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

I've already posted an answer, but here's another way: use `object`'s.

```
object TheMethod(MyEnum type)
{
    if (type == MyEnum.A) return (object)SubMethod1();
    else if (type == MyEnum.B) return (object)SubMethod2();
    //...
}

int SubMethod1() { return 1; }
string SubMethod2() { return "a"; }
```

And cast the result to the appropriate type.