# Method Overloading with different return type

Tags: c#, .net, oop, coding-style

I am want to dig in that whether it is an ambiguity or an extra feature that is provided:

```
 public class Foo 
 { 
    public int Bar(){
       //code
    }

    public string Bar(int a){
       //code
    }
 }
```

Any one having any experience with this, overloading on return type with different parameters should be a bad practice, is it?

But if the overloading was done on the basis of return type then why this is not working for.

```
 public class Foo 
 { 
    public int Bar(int a){
       //code
    }

    public string Bar(int a){
       //code
    }
 }
```

As it will be unable to decide which function to call 1st or second, if we call obj.Bar(); , it should end in error do any one have any idea about it why it allows first code snippet to run.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The C# specification (section 10.6) states that overloaded members may not differ by only return type and as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029.aspx

As per your question regarding creating parameters simply to support differing return types? I personally believe that is a terrible solution to the problem. Code maintenance will become difficult and unused parameters are a definite code smell. Does the method really need to be overloaded in that case? Or does it belong in that class? Should something else be created to convert from one return type to another? All things you should ask to derive a more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 21):

This is logically impossible. Consider the following call:

```
object o = Bar(42);
```

or even

```
var o = Bar(42);
```

How would the compiler know which method to call?

Edit:
Now that I understand what you're actually asking, I think overloading by meaningless parameters is bad practice, and diminished readability, it is much preferable to distinguish by method name:

```
 string BarToStr()
 {

 }

 int BarToInt()
 {

 }
```

Comment: The compiler could generate an error, *if it is unable to resolve the correct overload*. That would allow `string foo = BarToStr()`.  See the closed-as-duplicate answer for more.

Comment: It's maybe impossible within the current language. It certainly isn't "logically impossible". As Eric J., says, it would be quite easy to choose a method in case where the line is like `String foo = Bar()`. In cases like `Object foo = Bar()`, it seems to me that it would be quite easy to have programmers disambiguate with something like `Object foo = Bar<String>()`. A similar functionality with overloading by type parameter already exists. I don't think there's any practical reason this is impossible or infeasible, it just hasn't been implemented, perhaps for historical reasons.

Comment: Also shows the limitations of "var."

Answer (score 16):

Others already explained the situation. I only would like to add this: You can do what you have in mind by using a generic type parameter:

```cs
public T Bar<T>(int a) {
   // code
}
```

And call it like this:

```cs
int i = Bar<int>(42);
string s = Bar<string>(42);
```

The problem is that it is often difficult to do something meaningful with a generic type, e.g. you cannot apply arithmetic operations to it (at least before C# 11). Sometimes [generic type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) can help.

---

Starting with C# 11 you can declare abstract static interface members:

```cs
public interface IFactory<T> where T : IFactory<T>
{
    static abstract T Create(int input);
}
```

Applied in the Bar method:

```cs
public T Bar<T>(int a) where T : IFactory<T> {
   return T.Create(a);
}
```

Comment: What would the // code section look like? Can you do a switch statement on <T>?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9802588/880990

Comment: I assume that wouldn't work with non-native types.

Comment: For other types you must use if-else. But a better approach (if possible) is to define an interface and apply it as a generic type constraint `where T : IMyInterface`

Answer (score 5):

*You can not overload the function by differing only their return type*.
You can only overload the function in the following ways

1. Parameter types
2. Number of parameters
3. Order of the parameters declared in the method

You can not come to know which function is actually called (if it was possible).

One more thing I would like to add is 
function overloading is *providing a function with the same name, but with a different signature.* but the return type of a method is not considered as a part of the method's signature.

So this is another way to understand why method overloading can't be done only by return type.

Comment: This is partially untrue. The return type *is* part of the signature. In fact, the CLR allows overloading by return type, as do other languages, like F#. It's just that C# doesn't. Another way to look at it is that without the return type, one cannot uniquely describe the contract that a method or function adheres to.

Answer (score 2):

> any one having any experience with this, overloading on return type
>   with different parameters should be a bad practice, is it.

I'm taking that to mean - "is it bad practice to use differing parameter combinations to facilitate different return types" - if that is indeed the question, then just imagine someone else coming across this code in a few months time - effectively "dummy" parameters to determine return type...it would be quite hard to understand what's going on.

Edit - as ChrisLava points out "the way around this is to have better names for each function (instead of overloading). Names that have clear meaning within the application. There is no reason why Bar should return an int and a string. I could see just calling ToString() on the int"

Answer (score 1):

[C# does not allow it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6454eb8e-1496-4393-9abd-279ea5f4a491/return-type-as-part-of-a-methods-signature).

> C# on the other hand does not support method resolution based on the
>   return type; this was a conscious decision by the language designers
>   not to expose the feature of the CLR which allows it. There's no
>   technical reason why they couldn't have done, they just felt it better
>   not to. Because  the return value is not used for method selection a
>   C# method signature does not include it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create method with same name, same number and types of parameters.

For more details refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Check this.. You can't have method with same signature and just different return type. Recommended is mentioned in this question.

[C# Overload return type - recommended approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722362/c-sharp-overload-return-type-recommended-approach)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will result in a Compiler Error. You can not have a Method of the same name with the same parameters and a different return type, the caller would not know which Method to call (will not be able to resolve the location in Memory of the Method to call, why the Compiler would not allow it).  Your alternative would be to return an Object and Cast it based on what the Caller knows.  Even then, that appears to be Bad design.

This will Work (meaning Compile), but still bad design.

```
public class Foo
{
    public object Bar(int a)
    {
        return a;
    }
}
```