# How can I change a method's return type based on an argument value?

Tags: c#

How can I change this method's return type based on the value of returnType?
I want to return ints, floats, and decimals, without creating separate methods for each one. Specifically, how can I change the **decimal** in the first line based on the value of returnType??

```
public static decimal RequestNumber(string returnType)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(inputRequest);

        decimal result;

        switch(returnType)
        case decimal:
            bool parsed = decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);
        case int:
            bool parsed = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);
        case single:
            bool parsed = single.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);
        return result;
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: better start looking at how to use the `ConvertTo` method or change the type to be Int and pass in a decimal as an input parameter.. you need to go back to reading `C# Basics`

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate however it does add a spin to it with input param: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705643/method-overloading-with-different-return-type

Comment: Try to use Generics method to return T and return Func<ActualTypeHere> for each  string type detected.

Answer (score -2):

You could use object type and then cast the return result when calling;

```
private static object duo(string req)
{

    if (req == "Y")
    {
        string s = "Type String";
        return s;
    }
    else
    {
        List < string > l  = new List<string> { "Type", "List" };

        return l;
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
List<string> res = (List<string>)duo("H");
```