# Why doesn't the C# compiler resolve Delegate types only different in return type when passing a method group as parameter?

Tags: c#, delegates, method-group

Please consider the following code:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Foobar() { }
    static void Test(Action a) { }
    static void Test(Func<bool> a) { }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test(Foobar);
    }
}
```

It does not compile on VS2012. The compiler complains, that the reference to the method Foobar in the line `Test(Foobar)` is ambigious. This is the whole error message I get:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
'Program.Test(System.Action)' and 'Program.Test(System.Func<bool>)'
```

Now, the fix would be to just cast Foobar into an Action to force the correct overload: `Test((Action)Foobar)`.

But I am interested in the reason, why C# can't figure this out by himself? Why does he have to think that a `Func<bool>` would be an valid overload for a `void()`-function?

I know that you can not overload a method with another method that only differs in its return type. But that does not seem to be the case here. I am not overloading `Foobar()`. Sure, the return value may not be part of Foobar's signature, but why does this matter when it comes to convertion from method groups into delegates?

I am also aware of the problem, that the compiler sometimes refuses to cast method groups with overloaded methods into specific delegates, even if he could have all the information he needs, but I think that is a different problem (and a different error message). Again - Foobar is not overloaded. Only `Test()` is.

---

Edit: As Matthew pointed out, the problem is the same as the linked question. However, I am not 100% satisfied with the (very good) answer that Eric Lippert and Jon Skeet gave there.

In one part of his answer, Eric says:

> The principle here is that *determining method group convertibility requires selecting a 
>   method from a method group using overload resolution*, and **overload resolution does 
>   not consider return types**.

Any clue why is that? To me, it seems that a solution to the problem is exactly to change this sentence above and also consider the return type when choosing methods from a method group. Period, finished and everyone is happy, no? ;)

A practical example why this ambigious error sucks is, that `Task.Run()` can not be used on `void()`-methods of the own class without a cast. So even in some MSDN examples I saw, they used `Task.Run(() => Foobar())` instead of the much cleaner `Task.Run(Foobar)`.

Comment: Here's a discussion about overload resolution not considering return types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks for the link. Its always good to have references to related topics bundled together :). I just want to add, that I by no means suggest to allow method overloading by return types. I am wondering why "method selection from method groups to find compatible delegate conversions" have to be using the same rules as for method overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Because both delegates could be called without any parameter:

```
Action action = new Action(() => ...);
Func<bool> func = new Func<bool>(() => true);

action();
func(); // Legal even if you ignore the return value
```

The return type is not taken into account to resolve the overload.

Comment: Well, with this simple kind of reasoning, it should compile if you remove the declaration of `Test(Action a)` and only have `Test(Func<bool> a)` as possible method. Of course, it won't work since a "method returning a bool" is just not convertible into a "delegate not returning anything". You may be able to call them in similar ways, but that doesn't make the delegates implicit convertible.