# Overloading a function that returns a vector so that it can return a vector of different type

Tags: c++, vector, overloading, complex-numbers

I have had this problem at numerous times in my code (and now, I think there is no circumventing it): For some reason, when I try to write a method that returns a `std::vector<long double>` and try to overload it with the same method name that returns a different `std::vector`, say, `std::vector<std::complex<long double> >`, I get an error message akin to :
`std::vector<std::vector<long double> > cannot be overloaded with std::vector<long double>`
even though I the necessary classes #include'd. **Why is this?? Is there any rationale behind this??**

Here is some code simulating the problem:

```
#ifndef MATRIXALGORITHMS_H
#define MATRIXALGORITHMS_H
#include <complex>
#include <vector>

class MatrixAlgorithms
{
    public:
        MatrixAlgorithms();
        //two algorithms that are not strictly for matrices; they are for solving quadratic and cubic polynomials
        //quadratic method; the roots might be real, so there should be two versions of this algorithm
        std::vector<long double> quadraticFormula(long double, long double, long double);
        std::vector<std::complex<long double> > quadraticFormula(long double, long double, long double);
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // MATRIXALGORITHMS_H
```

I tried to compile it and it gave me the aforementioned error....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return type of a method is not used in an overload resolution.

Why ? Many reasons, but the simplest is because you wouldn't be able to guess what function is called when the returned value is ignored, which is perfectly legal.

E.g.:

```
int f();
double f();


f(); // Which one would you call ?
```

Other more complicated reasons can be easily found:

```
int f();
double f();

void g(int);
void g(double);

g(f()); // Which f and g do you call ?
```

Not to mention `auto` and so on...

Comment: I get it now; // I guess I needed an example independent of what I was working on...

Comment: Also, I found that there was no good reason to do the overload in my case; // since a real number IS a complex number with imaginary part of zero
/*I could have just returned a `std::vector<std::complex<long double> >` and checked if Im(roots[index]) == 0 */

Answer (score 3):

Return type does not take part in overload resolution.

Comment: I thought the question was *why* it is this way.

Comment: It is, so this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

The return type is not part of a function's signature. It doesn't really make much sense. How do you expect type deduction to work when only the return type changes? i.e.:

```
auto func = ambiguous(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // Which one to use?
```

You can specify an out parameter. This is a common idiom in Microsoft:

```
quadraticFormula(long double, long double, long double, TypeOne& out);
```

Although this will require your users to rely on Intellisense or documentation. The other option is to rename your functions.

```
quadraticFormulaOne(...);
quadraticFormulaTwo(...);
```

But this can be annoying if there's a lot of them.

---

> C++ (subsection 7.4.1 of Bjarne Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming
>   Language"): "Return types are not considered in overload resolution.
>   The reason is to keep resolution for an individual operator or
>   function call context-independent. Consider:
>
> ```
> float sqrt(float);
> double sqrt(double);
>
> void f(double da, float fla)
> {
>     float fl = sqrt(da);     // call sqrt(double)
>     double d = sqrt(da); // call sqrt(double)
>     fl = sqrt(fla);            // call sqrt(float)
>     d = sqrt(fla);             // call sqrt(float)
> }
> ```
>
> If the return type were taken into account, it would no longer be
>   possible to look at a call of sqrt() in isolation and determine which
>   function was called."

See [Function overloading by return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type) for an extensive discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the vector; **you can't overload on return type**.

> `[C++11: 13.1/2]:` Certain function declarations cannot be overloaded:
>
> - **Function declarations that differ only in the return type cannot be overloaded.**
> - *[..]*

As for the rationale: well, how would the compiler know which function you meant to call? It can only choose based on the arguments you give it.

Your expectation is rather akin to walking into a restaurant, and initiating the following interaction:

> `<mike_warren>` Good evening. I would like my favourite meal, please.
>   `<waiter>` What is your favourite meal, sir?
>   `<mike_warren>` That information is not available to you.
>   `<waiter>` Could you provide any hints or tips that may enable me to determine which food you would like served?
>   `<mike_warren>` No, sorry. You will only find out what my favourite food is after you have served it.
>   `<waiter>` Sir, that doesn't make a lot of sense. I cannot serve your favourite food without knowing in advance what it is… only from that information will the chef know how to prepare your meal.
>   `<mike_warren>` Then I think we have a problem.
>   `<waiter>` Leave before I call the police.