# Can we make overload methods with same name but having different datatypes within in a Class

Tags: c#

```
Class StudentFeeCollection
{
public static bool CheckAdmissionMonth(int AdmissionNo)
 {
 }
public static DataTable CheckAdmissionMonth(int AdmissionNo)
 {
 }
}
```

Is this possible or not, please tell me.

Comment: For future reference, the compiler in your IDE could have told you this. Try to do a little exploring on your own before looking for someone to tell you--it will aid your learning greatly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [out parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx):

```
 class StudentFeeCollection
{
public static void CheckAdmissionMonth(int AdmissionNo, out bool result)
{
    ........
}
public static void CheckAdmissionMonth(int AdmissionNo, out DataTable tbl)
{
    .......
}
```

Comment: Its just implementing function overloading

Comment: @AlexD, Its a solution as per the question. It has not been mentioned about interface in the question

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. You need to make sure that the signature of each overload is unique.

From the documentation:

```
Changing the return type of a method does not make the method unique as stated 
in the common language runtime specification. You cannot define overloads that 
vary only by return type.
```

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229029(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Imagine you're the compiler or the runtime--how would you know which return type the code was asking for? If you really need to support returning multiple datatypes from a method, using generics is your best bet. That said, looking at your specific example, I suggest not doing it here. Having one method that returns either a boolean or a `DataTable` seems like a pretty shoddy design.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload by argument types in c# but not by return type.
As Arshad said you can use out/ref parameters since these are arguments and not return types.

Also you can't overload by generic constraints of arguments(say having 2 versions where one is a struct and another is a class). see https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints.aspx

one reason to avoid return type overloading, from the c++ language description:

> The reason is to keep resolution for an individual operator or function call context-independent.

note: in some programming language like haskell you can overload by return types
see [Function overloading by return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type) for more info