# Function overloading with the only change in "uint32_t" & uint64_t" in pure virtual function in c++

Tags: c++, oop, overloading

I've a pair pure virtual function defined inside a c++ class, which I've overloaded. 
Code snippet below::

```
virtual uint64_t Abc::GetValue()=0; 
virtual uint32_t Abc::GetValue()=0;
```

Here, the only difference in function signature is the return type of GetVal() "`uint32_t`" & "`uint64_t`"..

It's throwing compilation error that this can't be overloaded.

Plz help me on this.

Comment: So if you do `abc.GetValue()`, which one should it call?

Comment: That whole thing about differences only in return type does not an overload make... yeah, thats biting you right now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function overloading by return type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't overload based on return type, only on parameter types. This is because the overload is chosen based on how the function is called, and a function call doesn't specify the expected return type.

Options include:

- Give the functions different names;
- "return" the value via a reference parameter, rather than the return value;
- add a dummy parameter, with a different type for each version, to specify the return type;
- return a "proxy" object that's convertible to either type (although this means you'll only have a single function, so derived classes can't override the two versions separately).

Answer (score 1):

In c++ onverloading is only done on the **parameters** of the function not on the **return type**. So your are redefining the same function which is an error.