# Why does C# not consider the return type of a function in polymorphism?

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism, overloading

There are two functions with same name and same set of parameters but with different return types. Why is it not a form of polymorphism i.e. method overloading? Why is it not allowed by compiler?

Comment: It's a duplicate, but - as a side note - Ceylon (a lesser known JVM language) has a very interesting type system which introduces intersection and union types. See http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/current/tour/types for more info.

Comment: @KonradMorawski Correct me if I'm wrong, but those features would not help with disambiguating which overload should be called. At most, they'd allow giving a single type to a set of overloads.

Comment: @delnan probably you're right, but still - if I understand it well, I never used Ceylon myself, only read about it - they could be used as a workaround if one insisted to have `int Foo()` and `bool Foo()` side by side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type deals with the same problem. It's not C# specific.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226583/should-a-question-about-the-design-of-c-be-closed-as-a-duplicate-of-a-java-ques/226584?noredirect=1#226584

Answer (score 16):

Because C# is designed so that types can be analyzed from *inside* to *outside*.  Imagine if you have

```
int N() {}
float N()() {}
```

and then a call

```
float x = N();
```

OK, great, obviously we could say that the float version was wanted. But then you say:

```
void M(int x) {}
void M(float x) {}

M(N());
```

OK, now which version was wanted?  The rule is **figure out what N() means** and then figure out what the best overload of `M` is **once you know what N() means**.  You reason from *inside* to *outside*.

Overload resolution based on return type requires reasoning from *outside* to *inside* and that can be a *lot* harder.

Comment: +1 : The effort required to read and disambiguate code first glance would be greatly decreased if return-type polymorphism were allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following:

```
int combine(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

float combine(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

If I were to call combine(1, 2), there is no way for the compiler to know which of the two methods I want to call (it's ambiguous).

You could almost make a case for checking return types, but what about:

```
var c = combine(1, 2);
dynamic d = combine(1, 2);
combine(1, 2);
```

In the above, what should the value of c or d be?  3?  -1?  It's impossible to tell.  How about the last statement, where there's no value being assigned?  I didn't define an overload that returns void, so which of the two methods should it call?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid ambiguity at the call site. Consider the following interface:

```
interface ISomething{
  int DoSomething()
  void DoSomething()
}
```

now when you call

```
myISomething.DoSomething()
```

which should be called?

Comment: Well it should call `void` because you didn't assign it to anything.if that's the only reason... you could give better example.

Comment: @Selman22 : That's daft. You're proposing changing the entire rules of the language, breaking backwards compatibility and introducing a an extra layer of checks that must be made simply to read the code correctly. This would introduce coding mistakes. At the end of the day it is what it is. It's not going to change. I prefer it the way is.

Comment: I'm not proposing anything.I'm just saying if that's the only problem, compiler can figure out that and see if you don't assign returning result to anything it could call the second method which is more appropriate then the ambiguity would be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not compulsory to assign the return type to a variable. the compiler can not enforce to assign the returned value to a variable. even if it enforces to do so, it makes no sense to stop assigning a integer value to a float. as shown in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be implemented with a complex set of rules (enforcing unambiguity), but it would introduce numerous ways of accidentally breaking the code.

It would bring along many confusing language quirks due to how inevitably complex the rules would be (kind of like comparison operators in PHP).

Is it worth it? What do we gain by this. The question "why not" should be reversed: why yes?