# Let a function return any type in C++ class

Tags: c++

I've got this class:

```
#define TYPE_INVALID 0x00
#define TYPE_BYTE    0x01
#define TYPE_SHORT   0x02
#define TYPE_INT     0x03
#define TYPE_LONG    0x04
#define TYPE_FLOAT   0x05
#define TYPE_DOUBLE  0x06

class BASIC_TYPE
{
    private:
        int8_t  type;
        int8_t  byteValue;
        int16_t shortValue;
        int32_t intValue;
        int64_t longValue;
        float   floatValue;
        double  doubleValue;

    public:
        BASIC_TYPE();
        template<typename T> BASIC_TYPE(int8_t, T);

        template<typename T> void set(T);
        template<typename T> T    get();
};

BASIC_TYPE::BASIC_TYPE()
{
    type = TYPE_INVALID;
}

template<typename T> BASIC_TYPE::BASIC_TYPE(int8_t newType, T value)
{
    type = newType;
    set(value);
}

template<typename T> void BASIC_TYPE::set(T value)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case TYPE_BYTE   : byteValue   = value; break;
        case TYPE_SHORT  : shortValue  = value; break;
        case TYPE_INT    : intValue    = value; break;
        case TYPE_LONG   : longValue   = value; break;
        case TYPE_FLOAT  : floatValue  = value; break;
        case TYPE_DOUBLE : doubleValue = value; break;
    }
}

template<typename T> T BASIC_TYPE::get()
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case TYPE_BYTE   : return byteValue;
        case TYPE_SHORT  : return shortValue;
        case TYPE_INT    : return intValue;
        case TYPE_LONG   : return longValue;
        case TYPE_FLOAT  : return floatValue;
        case TYPE_DOUBLE : return doubleValue;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the get()-function to output the stored number like this:

```
BASIC_TYPE val1(TYPE_INT, 1234);
BASIC_TYPE val2(TYPE_DOUBLE, 3.1415926535);

val1.set(5678);
val2.set(2.7182818284);
printf("%d\n%f\n", val1.get(), val2.get());
```

But g++ says that there is `no matching function call to 'BASIC_TYPE::get()` at the `printf`-function and that the `template argument deduction/substitution failed` (`couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'`).

What has to be changed to let the code compile properly?

Comment: Are you just reinventing `boost::any`?

Comment: This would be much more memory efficient with all typed private members in a union

Comment: @KerrekSB : in some cases having a dependency to boost is not a good idea.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's OK to have your own idions implemented for such stuff IMHO. It's easy to overcome this error at least.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Hmm. C++ already has a native, built-in mechanism for discriminating types at runtime. It feels like a wasted opportunity not to use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"What has to be changed to let the code compile properly?"*

You need to be explicit in this case. Just write

```
printf("%d\n%f\n", val1.get<int>(), val2.get<double>());
                        // ^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^
```

C++ cannot distinguish the various `get()` function instantiations just by return type (other as it can with `set()` where `T` appears as parameter type).
In such case, you'll need to specify the type to instantiate the templated function explicitely (as shown above).

---

Also note: I'd prefer to use an `enum` instead of those `#define TYPE_xxx` statements:

```
enum MySupportedTypes {
    TYPE_INVALID ,
    TYPE_BYTE    ,
    TYPE_SHORT   ,
    TYPE_INT     ,
    TYPE_LONG    ,
    TYPE_FLOAT   ,
    TYPE_DOUBLE  ,
};
```

For the implementation of your `get()` template function, you should consider something like this<sup>1</sup>, to avoid the `get()` function being called for an inappropriate requested type.

```
template<typename T> T BASIC_TYPE::get() {
    switch(type) {
        case TYPE_BYTE: 
            std::is_same<T,int8_t> ? return byteValue : throw std::bad_typeid;
        case TYPE_SHORT: 
            std::is_same<T,int16_t> ? return shortValue : throw std::bad_typeid;
        //  analogous ...
    }
}
```

Or even better provide a mechanism that will catch type mismatching at compile time.

---

1) See the documentation reference of [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)

Comment: was wondering why OP didn't declare class member of type T, and store the value there

Comment: I have a feeling the OP wants `val` to *remember* which of its member types is currently active and return that one, but I'm speculating.

Comment: @giorgim You can use static binding for such kind of stuff. We use such things with our embedded firmware. It's a bit more complicated to get it working properly, and ensure compile time errors for wrongly chosen types, of course.

Comment: @KerrekSB Certainly, they want that. As mentioned in my previous comment, getting the whole thing correct and checked at compile time or run time, there's needed more.

Comment: @StackerJ You should consider about the other implications I have maneitoned, when you're directing this solution path.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yes, I also now use the `enum` and the `std::is_same`-function. It is very good that the code is much clearer and safer now!

Answer (score 0):

You want to overload by return type, which C++ doesn't really let you do easily. I'll point out, however, that your final example needs you to tell it the type you want anyway because the parameters can be of any type. Even if C++ let you overload by return type, it still wouldn't know what type you wanted.

That said, there is an ugly trick you can use to overload on return type. I learned it can be used for this while looking into how to overload by return type, here: [Function overloading by return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type)

Behold:

```
class BASIC_TYPE
{
    // Your stuff, then:
    operator int (){ if (type != TYPE_INT) throw std::bad_typeid; return intValue; }
    operator float (){ if (type != TYPE_FLOAT) throw std::bad_typeid; return floatValue; }
    // And so on for every supported type
}
```

With this, you don't even need a get function, you can just call the value itself:

```
BASIC_TYPE val1(TYPE_INT, 1234);

//float bad = val1; // throws bad_typeid
int good = val1; // sets good to 1234
```

You can use casts to get the specific one you want in case you're getting casted to the wrong type.

If you overload the constructor and assignment operator, you can even get rid of the ugly syntax you have for declaring types:

```
class BASIC_TYPE
{
    public:
        // Constructors
        BASIC_TYPE(int i):type(TYPE_INT),intValue(i){}
        // So on for the other types
        // Assignment
        BASIC_TYPE & operator=(int i){ if (type != TYPE_INT) throw std::bad_typeid; intValue = i; return *this;} 
}

BASIC_TYPE intType (1234); // TYPE_INT chosen autmatically
// intType = 1.0; // throws
intType = 4321;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to store six different data members for six different types. They can be merged into a union. Also the `type` flag can be set with template metaprogramming. No need to do so explicitly in the constructor. In using the union, it is necessary to ensure that the template param of the get function matches the actual type of the object. In this case I chose to just return a zero initialized value of the type of the template param, if that type does not match the type of the object. You could chose to throw an exception instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#define TYPE_INVALID 0x00
#define TYPE_BYTE    0x01
#define TYPE_SHORT   0x02
#define TYPE_INT     0x03
#define TYPE_LONG    0x04
#define TYPE_FLOAT   0x05
#define TYPE_DOUBLE  0x06

using namespace std;

class BASIC_TYPE
{
    private:
        int8_t  type;
        union
        {
            int8_t  byteValue;
            int16_t shortValue;
            int32_t intValue;
            int64_t longValue;
            float   floatValue;
            double  doubleValue;
        }
        data;

    public:
        BASIC_TYPE();
        template<typename T> BASIC_TYPE(T);
        template<typename T> void set(T);
        template<typename T> T    get();
};

BASIC_TYPE::BASIC_TYPE()
{
    type = TYPE_INVALID;
}

template<typename T> BASIC_TYPE::BASIC_TYPE(T value)
{
    set(value);
}

template<typename T> void BASIC_TYPE::set(T value)
{
    if (is_same<T, int8_t>::value)
    {   
        type = TYPE_BYTE;
        data.byteValue = value;
    }   
    else if (is_same<T, int16_t>::value)
    {
        type = TYPE_SHORT;
        data.shortValue = value;
    }
    else if (is_same<T, int32_t>::value)
    {
        type = TYPE_INT;
        data.intValue = value;
    }
    else if (is_same<T, int64_t>::value)
    {
        type = TYPE_LONG;
        data.longValue = value;
    }
    else if (is_same<T, float>::value)
    {
        type = TYPE_FLOAT;
        data.floatValue = value;
    }
    else if (is_same<T, double>::value)
    {
        type = TYPE_DOUBLE;
        data.doubleValue = value;
    }
    else
        type = TYPE_INVALID;

}

template<typename T> T BASIC_TYPE::get()
{
    T ret{};
    if (type == TYPE_BYTE && is_same<T, int8_t>::value)
        ret = data.byteValue;
    else if (type == TYPE_SHORT && is_same<T, int16_t>::value)
        ret = data.shortValue;
    else if (type == TYPE_INT && is_same<T, int32_t>::value)
        ret = data.intValue;
    else if (type == TYPE_LONG && is_same<T, int64_t>::value)
        ret = data.longValue;
    else if (type == TYPE_FLOAT && is_same<T, float>::value)
        ret = data.floatValue;
    else if (type == TYPE_DOUBLE && is_same<T, double>::value)
        ret = data.doubleValue;

    return ret;
}
```