# How do you specialize a templated method with no parameters in a non-templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

I'm trying to specialize a templated method in a non-templated class, where the method's return type includes the templated type - this method takes no arguments. I've been searching around and trying to get things to compile through trial and error to no avail.

How do I get this code to build? Is such syntax even possible? (The templated method I'm trying to specialize is `cBar::getFoos`, as marked in the comments below.)

Stripped-down example code below:

```
#include <vector>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// the non-templated class below contains std::vector objects of these types
// (tBuiltInType is an int, float, or bool - but hopefully that's not an
// assumption that needs to be made, as I'd like to include more complex types)
template< typename tBuiltInType >
class cFoo
{
public:
    // ...

    void doSomething()
    {
        // ... (unimportant what happens here, but stuff happens)
    }

private:
    std::vector< tBuiltInType > m_objects;
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// this contains the templated method I'm trying to specialize - getFoos
class cBar
{
public:
    // ...

    // this is the method I'm trying to specialize by contained type (see private area)
    // getFoos< int >() would return m_intFoos, etc.
    template< typename tBuiltInType >
    std::vector< cFoo< tBuiltInType > > &getFoos();

    // (probably unimportant) example use    
    template< typename tBuiltInType >
    void doSomething()
    {
        for ( cFoo< tBuiltInType > &foo : getFoos< tBuiltInType >() )
            foo.doSomething();
    }

private:
    std::vector< cFoo< int > >   m_intFoos;
    std::vector< cFoo< bool > >  m_boolFoos;
    std::vector< cFoo< float > > m_floatFoos;
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// some (also probably unimportant) example usage code
int main()
{
    cBar bar;
    bar.doSomething< int >();
    bar.doSomething< bool >();
    bar.doSomething< float >();

    return 0;
}
```

(I'm visiting my family and have no laptop, so my usual dev setup isn't available - I could post errors from attempts in online compilers I've been trying instead, but I doubt it'd do much good here since not many will see an arcane online compiler error and know what to do from that, so I'll skip over that bit for sake of compacting the question text a little bit.)

Comment: See this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582408/let-a-function-return-any-type-in-c-class) please (at least the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27583037/1413395)).

Comment: That could work, but I'd like to add more complex types in the future. Thanks though!

Comment: _"but I'd like to add more complex types in the future."_ We've been solving this using some special preprocessor macros to extend the enumeration, and add type complicance verifying macros and code, to have all of this checked at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want `getFoos<int>()` to return `m_intFoos` etc? I think the simplest way is to introduce an empty tag-dispatch type:

```
template <typename T> struct empty { };

template< typename tBuiltInType >
std::vector< cFoo< tBuiltInType > >& getFoos() 
{
    return getFoosImpl(empty<tBuiltInType>{} );
}
```

And then provide the correct overloads:

```
std::vector< cFoo<int> >& getFoosImpl(empty<int> ) { return m_intFoos; }
std::vector< cFoo<bool> >& getFoosImpl(empty<bool> ) { return m_boolFoos; }
std::vector< cFoo<float> >& getFoosImpl(empty<float> ) { return m_floatFoos; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just go ahead and specialize it, out of class:

```
template<>
std::vector< cFoo< int > >& cBar::getFoos() { return m_intFoos; }
```

[Working example](http://rextester.com/QUS27415)