# c++ Does the return type of a function cause ambiguity?

Tags: c++, methods, return-type, ambiguity, ambiguous

While making a very simple program, I started wondering about whether the return value of a method has any participation in making a method ambiguous?

for example (not the case I was wondering about this is just a simple example to support my question):

```
int    CalculateSum(double firstNumber, double secondNumber);
double CalculateSum(double firstNumber, double secondNumber);
```

Are these two methods ambiguous or not?

On [Function overloading by return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type),  I read that overloading with return type is possible so does that mean that a return type does have a participation in a method being ambiguous?

Comment: That link doesn't say it's possible in C++, which it's not.

Comment: @JosephMansfield That link indeed doesn't say it's possible in C++, but it also doesn't say it's *not* possible, and in rare cases, it *is* possible. (Those rare cases involve importing functions from different namespaces, and having a case where the return type participates in overload resolution, such as conversion to a function pointer type.)

Comment: The overloading in C++ is implemented by 'name mangling'. You can compile the program and check how name `CalculateSum` is mangled in both variants. That should give you a hint how the compiler treats this situation.

Comment: @user4419802 Where a compile-time error of course makes it impossible to see the mangled name, but still answers the question. :)

Comment: @hvd Just make two versions and check them independently ;-) BTW. You didn't provide the actual errortext.