# Discriminate functions with different return type [Java], are there any tricks to resolve this issue?

Tags: java, generics, overloading

> Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and
>   argument types.

Due to the java specification I know, that we cannot have two methods with the same name, have same parameter types, but different return type. In other words it is impossible to overload functions with different return type.

Lets consider I have got two methods:

Method1:  `get(String s) return ObjectA;`

Method2: `get(String s) return ObjectB;`

The error will occure due to duplicate of method. I tried to resolve it using generics:

`T get(String s) return (T) Object;`

Now I can call function, using for example:
`ObjectA = (ObjectA) get("FooBar");`
And it works.

But the problem is, I would like to return particular object without casting it in the 'main' so

`ObjectA = get("FooBar");`

instead of

`ObjectA = (ObjectA) get("FooBar");`

Is there any trick, to discriminate functions by return type? Maybe add another parameter? Use interface? I simply have no idea how to solve this problem in Java.

I found a 'trick' in C++, so it can be made in other languages.
[Function overloading by return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type)

Comment: Why not just give them different names?

Comment: What you're trying to do, as you rightly say, is not allowed in Java so I would suggest you rework your code to avoid this situation. In your situation there's no way for the complier or developer to know which method will or even should be called in any given invocation. Don't look for a trick to work around it, just don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Rename one of the methods. If methodA returns different information than methodB, even if the return type is the same, there's no syntactical or design reason why they should both be called methodA. If you're in a situation where you absolutely need it to be the same method, then you should add a parameter letting you specify which functionality you need.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this does not match exactly your case but something similar to your question can be obtained using one or more `interface`.

In the code below the object returned by the `get(String s)` method call is an interface type and can be bound to the class which represents the result type.

```
//result type
interface IIinterface0 {
    void someMethod();
}

interface IIinterface1 {
    IIinterface0 get(String s);
}

class ClassA0 implements IIinterface0 {
    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
    }
}

class ClassA1 implements IIinterface0 {
    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
    }
}

class ClassA implements IIinterface1 {
    @Override
    public IIinterface0 get(String s) {
        IIinterface0 obj = new ClassA0();
        System.out.println(s + " " + obj.getClass().getName());
        return obj;
    }
}

class ClassB implements IIinterface1 {
    @Override
    public IIinterface0 get(String s) {
        IIinterface0 obj = new ClassA1();
        System.out.println(s + " " + obj.getClass().getName());
        return obj;
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "myString";

        IIinterface1 objectA = new ClassA();
        objectA.get(s);

        IIinterface1 objectB = new ClassB();
        objectB.get(s);
    }
}
```

The above prints:

> myString ttest.ClassA0
> myString ttest.ClassA1

Answer (score 1):

There is no trick. As you mentioned yourself this is forbidden by java language specification. This limitation BTW is inherited from C++ and is derived from the fact that return value of method can be ignored, i.e. you can just call

get("foo")

Which of 2 `get()` methods is expected to be executed now? We don't know and cannot know.

The typical solution however exists. You can define 1 method as following:

T get(String arg, Class type);

Now you do not need casting. You can call either

```
String s = get("foo", String.class);
```

or

```
Integer i = get("bar", Integer.class);
```

The problem now is in implementation. You can 
1. writer a if-else chain (ugly but simple solution)
2. Delegate implementation to small implementors stored in map, i.e.

```
interface Get<T> {
    public T get(String arg);
}


class StringGet implements Get<String> {
    public String get(String arg) {....}
}

class IntegerGet implements Get<Integer> {
    public Integer get(Integer arg) {....}
}


.........................

private Map<Class<?>, Get<?>> getters = ................;
```

T get(String arg, Class type) {
      return (T)getters.get(type).get(arg); // The casting must be here...
   }