# Alternative to function overloads

Tags: kotlin, overloading

The below code

```
fun getValue(): Int {
   return 42
}

fun getValue(): String {
   return "Foo"
}
```

gives the following error:

> **Conflicting overloads**: local final fun getValue(): String defined in
>   main, local final fun getValue(): Int defined in main.

Is there any way to get around this without renaming one of the functions?

Comment: ... why would you want to do that?

Comment: How do you intend to use those functions? Even theoretically?

Comment: @user202729 It has become abundantly clear that I wouldn't want to do that. The code snippet was a result of my misunderstanding on overloading. I appreciate everyone schooling me!

Comment: Some languages actually support this --- it's not as stupid a question as people are suggesting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type for a good writeup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, writing explicit getters in Kotlin is discouraged and it is suggested to use the following instead:

```
val value : Int get() = 42
val value : String get() = "Foo"
```

However, this still doesn't solve your problem. Since you did not give us any information *why* you need a declaration like this I can only give you some suggestions:

1. Find a more meaningful name for both variables other than `value`. For example:

   ```
   val intValue get() = 42 // note that you can omit :Int in this case
   val textValue get() = "Foo"
   ```
2. If both values are bound together, you can use a `Pair`:

   ```
   val value get() = 42 to "Foo"
   ```

   Now, you can access the two values via `value.first` and `value.second`. Note that `to` is an [infix function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation) that creates a `Pair`, so the above is equivalent to the more verbose notation

   ```
   val value : Pair<Int, String> get() = Pair(42, "Foo")
   ```
3. If `value` is something that's worth storing in its own object rather than using a `Pair`, you could create your own data class for it:

   ```
   data class MyData(val intVal : Int, val textVal : Text)
   val value get() = MyData(42, "Foo")
   ```

With solutions *2* and *3* it will be possible to use a [destructuring declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-declarations), like this:

```
val (intVal, textVal) = value
```

Answer (score 2):

```
inline fun <reified T> getValue(): T =
        when (T::class) {
            Int::class -> 42 as T
            String::class -> "foo" as T
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
```

You could use a generic inline function with a reified type parameter.
The given code block is inlined on each invocation.

The drawback is that the compiler can't check for wrong type parameters. You will get an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: I think the OP should reconsider if its really neccessary to have two variables/getters with the same name rather than using a solution like this

Comment: Thank you for actually answering the question as asked!

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** No.

**Long anser:** A function signature consists of the name of that function and its parameter list.

Since the return type does not belong to the signature the compiler can not distinguish which function to use when you call:

```
val v = getValue() // should v be inferred to Int or String?
```

Not even specifying the return type explicitely solves the problem:

```
val v: Int = getValue()
```

because `getValue()` is evaluated first without "knowing" where the return value will be assigned.

So, the best option you have is to choose a different name for one of the functions.

Answer (score 1):

How should the client specify which value he actually wants to get out of an instance of your class? These method names are ambiguous.

Look at the method signatures, only the **return types** differ, which is insufficient.

The rules for **overloaded methods** for Java also apply to Kotlin:

> Overloaded methods are **differentiated by the number and the type of the arguments** passed into the method.

In your case, just give appropriate distinguishable names. You could also simply make those values properties if your class, no need to explicitly define default getters.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to use a Java doc source for a Kotlin problem, although both run on the JVM.

Comment: It’s relevant since the rules also apply to Kotlin overloads

Comment: Kotlin is a multiplatform language and has three implementations so far: JDK, JS and native. It has strong links to the JVM, but this is not a formal relationship.

Comment: BTW there _is_ such a thing as the "[Kotlin Language Specification](https://jetbrains.github.io/kotlin-spec/#_name_and_overload_resolution)", only it's mostly TODOs at the moment.

Comment: I don’t think that’s a reason for not referring to Java sources but it’s fine, removed it